Can't reinstall Webcam Software on HP DV5 Windows 7
Some time ago I uninstalled the HP DV5 Laptop Webcam drivers and software for privacy, to know "the webcam is not avaiable" (I know it sounds paranoid).
Today I tried to reinstall the software but it doesn't work.
The HP Webcam appears in "imaging devices" in the device manager from the control panel, but it's the generic driver provided by Windows, not the HP driver that actually works and is newer.
The cam software (one of those programs with recording capabilities and to add effects to your face, a simple thing) is not nstalled.
I've searched in the folders "Program Files", "Program Files (x86)", the start menu, the list of installed programs in the control panel, everywhere.
The computer is an HP Pavillion DV5 running Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1.
The installer of the HP Software is called "Webcam_Software_sp50497.exe".
I tried extracting it with 7zip (it worked) and running manually the setup file but the same thing happened and nothing was installed.
I also reinstalled just in case all the drivers and stuff like Directx and Vc Redist runtimes.
Here are the logs created by the HP Webcam Software installer:
-cpeExitCode.txt says only:
    ExitCode=0 

-HPMSWEBCAM.LOG says:
    13/12/2024 15:58:56,31    ----- "HP MediaSmart Webcam" ("4.1.2.3130") ----- 
    13/12/2024 15:58:56,31  Executing block: "HPMSWebcam" 
    13/12/2024 15:58:56,31  TouchInput detection: 0 
    13/12/2024 15:58:56,31  Installing MediaSmart Webcam ...
    13/12/2024 15:58:56,31  Uninstallation Dir: "" 
    13/12/2024 15:58:56,31  Current working directory: C:\Users\AdminNB\AppData\Local\Temp\pftCC36.tmp\src 
    13/12/2024 15:58:56,32  Install command: start /w setup.exe /S /v /qn /z/ms 
    13/12/2024 15:59:00,91  The Exit Code is: 0 
    13/12/2024 15:59:00,91  *** Block execution completed.  Status=-3 

-and finally wizinstaller.log says:
    Memory 4064 MB
    Executing on .\WizInstaller.ini on viernes, 13 de diciembre de 2024 at 15:58:56 for en_uy
    Executing '.\MsWebcamInstall.bat', Param '', Working Directory 'C:\Users\AdminNB\AppData\Local\Temp\pftCC36.tmp'
    Wizinstaller Instance ID     : {788D1A6E-E326-4A1A-8F22-135A4E7B0E16}
    Init     : 63
    Action   : 4680
    Uninit   : 0
    Memory 4064 MB
    Executing on .\WizInstaller.ini on viernes, 13 de diciembre de 2024 at 16:02:30 for en_uy

Any ideas?

Please read your question in the format you see here and consider how you could [edit] it to be easier for other people to read. Especially, consider the use of "it" where that is ambiguous. We want to help you, but please don't make it difficult to understand what you are asking ;)

Ok, I'll try to reformat the question.
The short version should be: can't reinstal HP webcam drivers on a laptop, tried everything, the installer just stops, not even an error message, but it makes some logs that I included in the original post.

I FOUND THE PROBLEM!!!. I use VLC to open all video formats, so I had uninstalled Windows Media Player from the Windows Features section of the Control Panel... I don't know why I thought "huh... maybe if I install this thing..." and guess what?. After installing Windows Media Player, THE HP WEBCAM INSTALLER WORKED PERFECTLY AND INSTALLED THE DRIVERS AND THE CAM SOFTWARE.
That's insane. Obviously I still have VLC as the default player, I don't want to use Windows Media Player, but it must have some shared dll or codec that the HP Webcam drivers needed.
So... I guess this can be closed?. I don't delete everything because maybe it helps somebody else.
The short version: if you can't install the web cam drivers in your HP laptop, make sure you have Windows Media Player installed. (facepalm).
